# Why the function GetElementById is returning NULL in Salesforce?

Tags: javascript, salesforce

This is my code, and always returns Null in the "if" sentence. The id exists. When I try to do `document.getElementById` in the console, it runs properly.

```html
<apex:component>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh() {
      var run = document.getElementById('db_ref_btn');
      if (run == null) {
        alert('Por favor, añade un Informe a la página de Inicio.');
      } else {
        document.getElementById('db_ref_btn').click();
      }
    }
    window.onload = setInterval(refresh);
  </script>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: because element's ID is different. Use dev tools to check the ID of element if its same or different

Comment: Also I would point out, even if this did work,. your db_ref_btn is going to get some hammering with that setInterval..

Comment: No, the ID is correct

Comment: I would change the setInterval if it runs

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what the problem here without seeing the HTML, if you using chrome from the console, what does typing document.getElementById('db_ref_btn') return?

Comment: This is the return: <input value="Refresh" class="btn" id="db_ref_btn" name="refresh" onclick="window.open('/000D34z?poll=1&amp;m=HOMEPAGE&amp;nr=1&amp;refresh=1', 'db_refresh_frame');" title="Refresh Dashboard" type="button">